# ssh forward 2 ports in one command. Is it possible?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I currently use ssh to forward ports to my localhost.   I have an application that requires two ports.  I can currently get it working if I run two separate ssh commands.   But I was wondering if it could be done with one?

First I forward port 80 to localhost 8080

```
ssh user@<MY_HOST> -p 2220 -L 8080:192.168.122.169:80
```

I then forward port 5000 to localhost 5000

```
ssh user@<MY_HOST> -p 2220 -L 5000:192.168.122.169:5000
```

If I run these two separate ssh commands it works.   But I was wondering if I could do this all with one ssh command?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do:

```
ssh user@<MY_HOST> -p 2220 -L 8080:192.168.122.169:80 -L 5000:192.168.122.169:5000
```